# ActionBar not showing properly on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm developing an application for smartphones and tablets.
My ActionBar consists of tabs for smartphones (ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) and action buttons for tablets (NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD).
The problem is that on smartphones, the tabs show up, but just below, two tab icons show up also, in what I would call a second actionBar. The rest of the action menu items are stacked normally on the bottom. See this image for more info :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoBPl.png

All my items in my menu layout are written like this :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
```

Those two icons should not show up. Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: here is the onCreateOptionsMenu method, it is very simple:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: I still did not found the answer to solve my problem...If you need more details please tell! thanks